# Resize a named range in Excel via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range that I need to resize according to how many values are in the named range.  For example, if there are ten items the range should be $A$1:$I11, but I need it to shrink as well as expand.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Generate()

Dim wsFail as Worksheet
Dim NextRow As Long, TotalRows As Long

Set wsFail = Sheets("Failure Report")

 wsFail.Activate
    NextRow = Sheets("Failure Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    TotalRows = Range("FailReportTable").Rows.Count
    Sheets("Failure Report").Range("A" & TotalRows).Resize(TotalRows, 9).Value & _
    = Range("FailReportTable").Columns("A:I").Value

End Sub
```

## Updated Code (Still not working)

```
With wsFail
    .Activate
        NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Range("FailReportTable").Cells(1, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row
        FirstCell = .Range("FailReportTable").Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False)
        LastCol = Split(.Range("FailReportTable").Cells(1, Range("FailReportTable").Columns.Count).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        NewRange = FirstCell & ":" & LastCol & NextRow
        .ListObjects("FailReportTable").Resize Range("NewRange")
End With
```

Comment: Just curious, why set the sheet but never use it afterwards?

Comment: Why not just use a dynamic named range?

Comment: I set the sheet for other parts of the script and to activate the sheet without having to type Sheets("Failure Report") every time.

Comment: The last line of this code makes no sense - I don't understand what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: By setting the sheet, you don't have to activate it. That's kinda the point XD And you do type `Sheets("Failure Report")` every time in the above code snippet (maybe not rest). Just curious.

Comment: It is supposed to resize a named range depending on the number of entries in the range.  I realize the script I posted is nonsensical...but it is all I have to go on right now.

Comment: Read the Dynamic Range portion of my article: http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2011/03/the-imposing-index.html

Comment: As @Excel Hero said - a dynamic named range will do the job.  `=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$I:$I,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))`  Providing there aren't any blank rows in column A this **non volatile** formula will reference your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final version to resize Named Range (with or without headers)

1. Change `FailReportTable` to your NamedRange's name
2. Change `Failure Report` to your NamedRange's sheet's name

Code :

```
Sub test_Gerasimos_Zap()

Dim wsFail As Worksheet, _
    FirstCell As String, _
    LastCol As String, _
    NextRow As Long, _
    NewRange As String

Set wsFail = Sheets("Failure Report")
With wsFail
    .Activate
        NextRow = .Cells(.Range("FailReportTable").Cells(1, 1).Row, .Range("FailReportTable").Cells(1, 1).Column).End(xlDown).Row
        FirstCell = .Range("FailReportTable").Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Address(False, False)
        LastCol = Split(.Range("FailReportTable").Cells(1, .Range("FailReportTable").Columns.Count).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        NewRange = FirstCell & ":" & LastCol & NextRow
    .ListObjects("FailReportTable").Resize Range(NewRange)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch." at the LastCol line.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `(0)` at the end of the line! Should be working properly now! Let me know

Comment: I get another run-time error (1004 this time).  It states that the range is invalid. the headers must remain in the same row and the resulting table must overlap the original table."  I thought my Clear line was causing an issue, but commenting it didn't change the results.  It throws the error up at '.ListObjects("FailReportTable").Resize Range(NewRange) '

Comment: Ok, this because the headers of a table are ignored when you use `NamedRange.Cells()`, I added the necessary `.Offset(-1,0)` to correct! Should be ok now!

Comment: It still does not want to shrink the range. It also includes A21, which is not a part of FailReportTable.  I started the test with 6 values and the NewRange value was A21:I26.  I removed a value, to a total of 5, and the NewRange value was still A21:I26.

Comment: Mkay, can you give me the initial range of the named range (with headers) and what is the result of the edit (little change) for NewRange variable?

Comment: The initial range of FailReportTable was A22:I26 and headers in A21:I21 (not included in FailReportTable). I get an error 1004 run-time error (application- or object-defined) at the NextRow line.  I input `?Range("FailReportTable").Rows.Count` into the immediate window and it returned the number 6.

Comment: So you don't have the headers in your NamedRange? I mean did you choose or not the option "My table has headers" when you created it? If you didn't get rid of the `Offset` in the `FirstCell` line. For the error on next row, I forgot to switch line and column when switching from Range to Cells.

Comment: I chose not to include the headers in the named ranges because there is a fair amount of backend work and the headers would complicate things.  This is only one piece to a larger puzzle.  It did not shrink.  The Local window indicates that the FirstCell value is "A21", the LastCol value is "I", the NextRow value is "26", and the NewRange value is "A21:I26".

Comment: Ok, so I got rid of the `Offset` as you don't have headers, everything else seems good from my end... Test without compiling the `NewRange` if you can shrink it properly by replacing `NewRange` in the `Resize` statement with a value of your choice (like `A22:I24`). Does it work?

Comment: No it does not work. It gives me another error (the same error that I had earlier) concerning the range being invalid.  I changed `NewRange` to `"A22:I24"` and it is still giving me issues.

Comment: ok and with `A21:I24`? I tried a few things on my own and even if you did not choose the "headers option" a the create of the table, it is included in the NamedRange! And as long as the headers stays on the same row, it appears to be working for me... :/

Comment: I changed `A22:I24` to `A21:I24` and it worked.  The range has been reduced to `A22:I24`.  Thank you for your help (even though it took a lot of effort on your part).  How would I adjust this to go back to using the named range instead of a cell reference in my code?  Would I adjust the FailReportTable range to include the headers?

Comment: Nope the range of the NamedRange already include the headers (try `MsgBox Sheets("Failure Report").ListObjects("FailReportTable").Range.Address`); So just try the edit, it works for me just fine. The only condition is that your **first column have to be fully filled** to properly detect the last row!

Comment: It is not resizing from `A21:I24`.  I do not know what is going on with this.  I am going to paste the code that I have so far as an update.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Here `MyRange` is defined as `$B$5$:$B$5$` only and the code expands it to all occupied cells as `$B$5:$E$11`.

[image: scr]

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim N As Long, M As Long, r As Range

    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange")
    N = CountRows(r)
    M = CountCols(r)

    Debug.Print r.Resize(N, M).AddressLocal
    ' $B$5:$E$11

End Sub

Public Function CountCols(ByVal r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountCols = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(0, 1)) Then
        CountCols = 1
    Else
        CountCols = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    End If
End Function

Public Function CountRows(ByVal r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Note to self. I could have used the `.Areas` property in the range also.